# Count the Words in text file without using the 'wc' command in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell

Here I could not find the number of words in the text file . What would be the possible changes do I need to make? 
What is the use of `tty` in this program?

```
echo "Enter File name:"  
read filename  
terminal=`tty`  
exec < $filename  
num_line=0  
num_words=0
while read line  
do  
    num_lines=`expr $num_lines + 1`  
    num_words=`expr $num_words + 1`  
done
```

Comment: Well for each line, you increment the word count by one. You need to find the word count in that line and add it to num_words.

Comment: Ok.. So for each of the line I need to assign "set $num_lines" command and then try to increment the Word count. Is that what you wanted to say ?

Comment: I didn't say anything about assigning anything to num_lines.. Each line has a few words in it. Currently you're counting one word per line and then simply proceed to the next. You need to count the words in a line. That's about it.

Comment: I tried,  `set $num_lines` and then add the statement `num_words`=`expr  $num_words + $#` . By adding $# ,instead of 1 it gives me the correct word count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way using arrays to read the number of words in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$1" ] || { 
    printf printf "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s\n" "${0//\//}"
    exit 1
}

fn="$1"

[ -r "$fn" ] || {
    printf "error: file not found: '%s'\n" "$fn"
    exit 1
}

declare -i cnt=0

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do        # read line from file
    tmp=( $line )                               # create tmp array of words
    cnt=$((cnt + ${#tmp[@]}))                   # add no. of words to count
done <"$fn"

printf "\n %s words in %s\n\n" "$cnt" "$fn"     # show results

exit 0
```

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/wordfile.txt

Here I could not find the number of words in the text file. What 
would be the possible changes do I need to make? What is the use 
of tty in this program?
```

**output:**

```
$bash wcount.sh dat/wordfile.txt

 33 words in dat/wordfile.txt
```

**wc -w confirmation:**

```
$ wc -w dat/wordfile.txt
33 dat/wordfile.txt
```

**tty?**

The use of `terminal=tty` assigns the terminal device for the current interactive shell to the `terminal` variable. (It is a way to determine which `tty` device you are connected to e.g. `/dev/pts/4`)

Answer (score 0):

`tty` command prints the name of the terminal connected to the standard output. In the context of your program, it does nothing significant really, you might as well remove that line and run.

Regarding the number of words calculation, you would need to parse each line and find it using space as the delimiter. Currently the program just finds the number of lines `$num_lines` and uses the same calculation for `$num_words`.

Comment: can I use "set $num_lines" and then increment the word count?